# Does manual kernel update affect the next regular automatic update?

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, updates

I installed the kernel 4.4.8 manually from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.8-wily/ to circumvent a bug. Now I wonder what will happen when this kernel gets officially distributed by the automatic update:

- Can this result in a conflict? Is it necessary to manually uninstall the kernel beforehand?
- Will this affect future updates? I mean is the line of updates broken by the manually installed kernel?

Answer (score 2):

Updates should still work normally once a newer version of the kernel is available from any of your defined software sources.

If you are interested you can see which version apt considers newer with this command:

```
dpkg --compare-versions [version1] gt [version2]
```

The exit status will be 0 if apt considers version1 newer or 1 otherwise.