# Will Ubuntu get patched against Meltdown and Spectre?

Tags: kernel, updates, security

> The following is a canonical post that attempts to cover a broad number of Meltdown and Spectre questions.  It is being maintained by Thomas Ward who is in contact with the Security and Kernel teams on this matter for other reasons as well.

I recently read about the [Meltdown and Spectre](https://meltdownattack.com/) vulnerabilities.  I was wondering, will Ubuntu be patching against the vulnerabilities?

And is there an ETA on a fix?

Comment: There's already a similar question here: [What is Ubuntu's status on the Meltdown and Spectre vulnerabilities?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/992232/what-is-ubuntus-status-on-the-meltdown-and-spectre-vulnerabilities).