# Meltdown / Spectre patch for 14.04 using kernel 3.16

Tags: 14.04, kernel, security, patch

Several of my servers are running 14.04 with kernel 3.16. The spectre / meltdown patches listed [on the Ubuntu help wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/KnowledgeBase/SpectreAndMeltdown?_ga=2.109228423.361718012.1515604883-1196863877.1515604883) don't indicate that 3.16 will be patched. Wondering if I should roll these servers back to 3.13? Or am I missing something?

Comment: That's right, 3.16 has not been supported for a long time. Either roll back to 3.13 (14.04), or roll forward to the [HWE stack for 14.04](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack).

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/questions/992232/what-is-ubuntus-status-on-the-meltdown-and-spectre-vulnerabilities "Any questions relating to status updates, or asking if anything is going to be patched for these vulnerabilities should be closed as duplicates of this question."