# Ubuntu 16.04.3 won't boot into linux 4.13

Tags: 16.04, boot, kernel

I waited for a while (Jan 29) before updating my system to fix the meltdown bug.  Linux 4.10 was working fine.  The update pushed 4.13.32 which won't boot, it just keeps restarting.  I can boot to 4.10.42 successfully.  Do I need to be concerned with future updates breaking something if I continue using 4.10.42 kernel?

H-P dc7900, Intel-64 bit cpu, 32-bit os

Comment: 4.10 was EOL 13-Jan-2018 and wasn't provided with meltdown/spectre fixes.   "The Rolling HWE kernel for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS moved to 4.13 early, as the 4.10 HWE kernel did not receive fixes"
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/KnowledgeBase/SpectreAndMeltdown  (last updated 2018-01-26)

Comment: If you are really concerned about Meltdown and Spectre you can upgrade to 14.14.15. Otherwise simply stay where you are on 4.10 until 4.13 works for you. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/992232/what-is-ubuntus-status-on-the-meltdown-and-spectre-vulnerabilities Go to the bottom of my answer there and substitute 14.14.15 where it says 14.14.13. Heed the warnings about manual kernel installations. In the mean time you should consider finding the bug causing the boot crash.