# Adaptec RAID 8805 aacraid driver issue in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, kernel, raid

I've been experiencing an issue with the Linux source code driver [provided by Microsemi for their Adaptec RAID 8805 RAID controller](https://storage.microsemi.com/en-us/downloads/linux_source/linux_source_code/productid=asr-8805&dn=adaptec+raid+8805.php).

Since upgrading from Linux kernel `v4.4.0-112` to `v4.4.0-116` in Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS the I've been unable to get the provided `aacraid` kernel module load, that allows the attached volumes to be used by the OS.

Looking at the kernel logs I see the following error messages, like:

```
aacraid: version magic '4.4.0-116-generic SMP mod_unload modversions ' should be '4.4.0-116-generic SMP mod_unload modversions retpoline '
```

I would guess this relates to the recent ['retpoline' patch](https://askubuntu.com/a/992459/763841) to the Linux kernel to address the Spectre vulnerabilities.

So far I have found the only solution to this issue is to roll back to kernel version `v4.4.0-112` or [manually force the version magic value](https://pietrotech.wordpress.com/2016/02/08/how-to-fix-magic-version-compatibility-of-kernel-modules-exec-format-error/) in the module via MODULE_INFO in the source code.

It should also be noted Microsemi also provide a [precompiled binary for Ubuntu 16.04](https://storage.microsemi.com/en-us/downloads/ubuntu/ubuntu_16/productid=asr-8805&dn=adaptec+raid+8805.php) but this is is only marked as compatible with Ubuntu 16.04.2 / kernel `v4.4.0-62`, as of driver `v1.2.15502`.

I was wondering if anyone was aware of a better remedy for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been in contact with [Microsemi support](https://www.microsemi.com/product-directory/4193-support), who produce the Adaptec RAID controllers.

I have been informed they are aware of this issue and their engineering team are looking into how to resolve it.

In the mean time their recommendation is to use their pre-compiled [Ubuntu binary](https://storage.microsemi.com/en-us/speed/raid/aac/linux/aacraid_linux_drivers_v1.2.1-55022_tgz.php) (which is built to work with the `linux-image-4.4.0-21-generic` kernel image) or else stick with `linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic` and the DKMS driver (if like in my situation you require a newer kernel version).

I have been given an incident ID: `180226-000003` which I would suggest you quote if you also are experiancing this issue and want to contact Mirosemi support.