# How to stop security update alerts?

Tags: updates

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 desktop system which I use for my everyday work. I get these "Update Available" notifications every time I boot up my system and they're very annoying. I've already shutoff automatic updates and I want to shut off notifications for updates.

How would I do this?

Thanks

Edit: I update my machine on a regular schedule, but sometimes I neither have the time nor the internet connection for an update to occur

Comment: Since this is bound to be asked, could you [edit] your question and explain why you don't simply update your machine?

Comment: "I want to shut off notifications for updates." and then you forget to update for months and months ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was going to post a question on this myself.

[image: update never.png]

I had set up all updates to never and every day it kept nagging me to update 500 MB of "stuff". I used the most current kernels from Ubuntu Mainline so got all my REPTOLINE spectre fix and KOPTI meltdown fix sooner than everyone else: [What is Ubuntu's status on the Meltdown and Spectre vulnerabilities?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/992232/what-is-ubuntus-status-on-the-meltdown-and-spectre-vulnerabilities/992459#992459)

Finally one day I accidentally updated everything, or it updated it anyway and now the messages to update no longer appear.

So if you set it to never **after** it's sent you the message once it will still nag you.

I've noticed comments tell you never to say never. However I was concerned with a raft of bugs that started appearing when Ubuntu team rushed out meltdown and spectre fixes.

Ironically there is no real virus and memory leaks only occur at 2KB per second when Speculative Execution Branching gets past 26 branches without a hit, or something like that. So on a 8 GB RAM machine would take a very, very long time to scrape all the memory. Not to mention some "brainiac" still has to piece it altogether.