# Ubuntu and Spectre Meltdown

Tags: security, bios, microcode

I have installed the latest BIOS on my notebook. The manufacturer of the notebook states that the BIOS update will include corrections regarding Spectre/Meltdown vulnerabilities.

- What microcode does Ubuntu 14.04 LTS use?
- Does it load the microcode from BIOS or does it load the microcode from the system files on the HD?
- When it uses the microcode from the HD, I am afraid it could be an older version which is not Spectre/Meltdown proof.
- How to check which microcode is loaded and used by the system and how to check which one is a newer version?

Comment: Are you regularly upgrading from the -security repository? If so, then you have all released patches for Spectre/Meltdown. The Ubuntu Security Team is quite prompt about pushing those patches out to all supported released of Ubuntu. If you are not regularly upgrading from the -security repository, then begin doing so, of course.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Ubuntu's status on the Meltdown and Spectre vulnerabilities?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/992232/what-is-ubuntus-status-on-the-meltdown-and-spectre-vulnerabilities)

Comment: I think that the BIOS loads its modifications first since it runs first and then the OS loads its modifications. I assume there's some versioning or something that tells it which takes priority.

Comment: @N0rbert I don't think that's a duplicate. That's more about whether and how far along Ubuntu is in solving the problem and won't answer at all what the situation is when both BIOS and Ubuntu try to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu does not use microcode (in the sense you are talking about) at all. Your CPU, however, does use microcode -- that is the code *it* needs to function.

Ubuntu provides amd- and intel-microcode packages, which provide updated firmware for that hardware. These packages are fully updated with all Spectre/Meltdown patches in all supported releases of Ubuntu.

Ongoing patches for vulnerabilities are handled by the Ubuntu Security Team. It's a normal part of *support* in a supported release of Ubuntu. You receive those patches routinely when you upgrade from Ubuntu's -security repository.

If you have questions about specific vulnerabilities, feel free to search the [database](http://security.ubuntu.com) of vulnerabilities and patches.

Determine which version of firmware your CPU is using with `grep microcode /proc/cpuinfo`

Finally, be aware that version numbers can misleading when checking for vulnerabilities: A patched package may not have a higher upstream version number (since it's not a new upstream version), but is still fixed and tested and no longer vulnerable. In these cases, Debian and Ubuntu add their own supplementary version numbers so you can tell the difference.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is:
It first loads the Microcode from the BIOS and **then**, while loading the OS, the newest Microcode is loaded again by the OS. Both are **signed** binary files which are supposedly impossible to tamper.

So if the version of the BIOS/UEFI is older than the version provided to the *Operating System*, the MicroCode is loaded/updated by the OS via a system update. Otherwise the BIOS/UEFI version is used.

The *Operating System* **does load** microcode during the booting process as mentioned in [this WiKi](https://wiki.debian.org/Microcode#CPU_microcode_non-freeness):

> The CPU-vendor-provided "opaque" update data itself, however, is non-free, and its contents are unknown to Debian. This "opaque" data is sent as-is to the CPU for processing, but only when the kernel and user-space utilities deem it necessary to do so. This means the microcode update is not sent to the system processor unless it is actually needed.
>
> For example, the system will never send microcode update data to the processor when the processor reports that its already running either the same version or a newer version of the microcode (because the UEFI/BIOS already updated it). It will also not send microcode update data that is not appropriate to that system processor.

Comment: What happens if there are conflicts (older vs newer versions of a fix, for example)?

Comment: I honestly don't know (Ask Intel), but the sane approach would be to only use the newest version.

Comment: OK. but is there a method to check the version of the microcode Ubuntu is loading from the OS? There is still a chance the microcode in the BIOS is newer than that of the OS if the microcode shipped by Intel is not Linux conform e.g.

Comment: @user535733: Ubuntu **does load** microcode to the processor if desired. See the edit of my answer.

Comment: @zx485 I'm gonna friendly-quibble it a teeny bit. While technically correct (it gets pulled from storage and briefly loaded into memory), the OS is simply the convenient delivery vehicle for a binary payload. It's not "loaded" in the typical sense of the OS or applications actually using it. Folks need to understand the difference, or they will think the OS is relevant to microcode. Good job locating the Debian docs!

Comment: @user535733: To complete our discussion: there are two ways of delivering a MicroCode update: First the BIOS/UEFI, second the OS. So if the first way doesn't work, the second has to do...

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex See some info [here](http://inertiawar.com/microcode/) The CPU will reject a microcode update if the version number is equal/less than the current microcode revision.