# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Spectre/Meltdown Status

Tags: 18.04, security, intel-cpu

I could not find any official Ubuntu information on that issue. 
If I check the official statement:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/KnowledgeBase/SpectreAndMeltdown
there is only information on Ubuntu 17.10 and earlier.
Is it possible to complete the "Kernel Mitigations" table on the wiki web page mensioned above with the Ubunut 18.04 LTS?

Comment: Confirmed duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/992232/what-is-ubuntus-status-on-the-meltdown-and-spectre-vulnerabilities - note that it has been updated slightly with changes proposed to me by the Ubuntu Security and Server teams to add a blurb about what kernel versions already ahve the fix.  (4.15.0 and higher kernels are all patched for this already)

Comment: Good question .

Answer (score 1):

All "Kernel Mitigations" available starting from 17.10 is valid for 18.04 and 18.10.

Official Ubuntu blog confirms it - https://blog.ubuntu.com/2018/01/04/ubuntu-updates-for-the-meltdown-spectre-vulnerabilities